# Destructor array stack tiwer hanoi c++ double pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, stack, destructor, towers-of-hanoi

I try to push element into the stack but it shownd that there is an error of space amount. The capacity upgraded if the length is bigger than the capacity. Does somebody know how to correct this error? I think that this may come from the destructor, but I am not so sure about this.

ArrayStack.cpp

```
#include "ArrayStack.h"

ArrayStack::ArrayStack() 
{
   maxCapacity = DEFAULT_CAPACITY;
   this->tab = new int* [DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
   this->topElement = 0;
   this->length = 0;
}

ArrayStack::~ArrayStack()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < maxCapacity; i++)
    {
        delete tab[i];
    }
    delete[] tab;
}

void ArrayStack::push(int element)
{
    this->length++;
    while (this->maxCapacity <= this->length) {
        maxCapacity += DEFAULT_CAPACITY;

        int** temp = new int* [maxCapacity];
        for (int i = 0; i < maxCapacity; i++)
        {
            temp[i] = tab[i];
        }
        delete tab;
        this->tab = temp;
    }
   
    this->tab[this->length] = new int (element);
    this->topElement = element;
    
}

void ArrayStack::pop()
{
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        throw Empty_Stack();
    }
    delete tab[this->length];

    this->length--;
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        this->topElement = -1;
    }
    else 
    {
        this->topElement = *tab[this->length];
    }


}

int ArrayStack::top() const
{
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        throw Empty_Stack();
    }
    return this->topElement;

}

bool ArrayStack::isEmpty() const
{
    if (this->length == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int ArrayStack::size() const
{
    return this->length;
}
```

ArrayStack.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Stack.h"
#include "NotImplementedException.h"
class ArrayStack : public Stack
{
public:
    static const int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;

    // ATTENTION, pour chacune des méthodes, lorsque
    // vous créez sa définition dans le .cpp, vous devez
    // remplacer {} (et éventuellement son contenu) par un ;
    ArrayStack();
    ~ArrayStack();
    void push(int element) override;
    void pop() override;
    int top() const override; 
    bool isEmpty() const override;
    int size() const override;

private:
    int length;
    int** tab;
    int topElement;
    int maxCapacity;

};
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a number of things wrong with how this class is managing its array:

- The constructor is allocating an array of `int*` pointers, but is not setting any of them to `nullptr` initially.  Which causes problems for the destructor, because it is calling `delete` on *every single pointer*, whether they have been initialized or not.  To avoid having to `delete` unused pointers, the destructor should be looping up to `length`, not `maxCapacity`.
- Likewise, `pop()` is not setting any freed pointers to `nullptr`, which also causes problems for the destructor when it loops up to `maxCapacity` rather than `length`.  It is also `delete`'ing the wrong array element, and going out of bounds if the array is at its max capacity.
- When `push()` allocates a new array (FYI, the outer `while` loop is unnecessary), it copies too many elements from the old array, which is smaller than the new array. Also, it is using `delete` instead of `delete[]` to free the old array.
- The class is not following the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), as it should implement (or at least disable) the copy/move constructors and copy/move assignment operators.

Try something more like this instead:

ArrayStack.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "Stack.h"
#include "NotImplementedException.h"

class ArrayStack : public Stack
{
public:
    static const int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;

    // ATTENTION, pour chacune des méthodes, lorsque
    // vous créez sa définition dans le .cpp, vous devez
    // remplacer {} (et éventuellement son contenu) par un ;

    ArrayStack();
    ArrayStack(const ArrayStack &src);
    ArrayStack(ArrayStack &&src);
    ~ArrayStack();

    ArrayStack& operator=(ArrayStack rhs);

    void push(int element) override;
    void pop() override;
    int top() const override; 
    bool isEmpty() const override;
    int size() const override;

private:
    int length;
    int** tab;
    int topElement;
    int maxCapacity;
};
```

ArrayStack.cpp

```cpp
#include "ArrayStack.h"
#include <utility>

ArrayStack::ArrayStack() 
{
   maxCapacity = DEFAULT_CAPACITY;
   tab = new int* [DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
   for (int i = 0; i < DEFAULT_CAPACITY; ++i) {
      tab[i] = nullptr;
   }
   length = 0;
   topElement = -1;
}

ArrayStack::ArrayStack(const ArrayStack &src)
{
   maxCapacity = src.maxCapacity;
   tab = new int* [maxCapacity];
   for (int i = 0; i < src.length; ++i) {
      tab[i] = new int (*(src.tab[i]));
   }
   for (int i = src.length; i < maxCapacity; ++i) {
      tab[i] = nullptr;
   }
   length = src.length;
   topElement = src.topElement;
}

ArrayStack::ArrayStack(ArrayStack &&src)
{
   maxCapacity = src.maxCapacity; src.maxCapacity = 0;
   tab = src.tab; src.tab = nullptr;
   length = src.length; src.length = 0;
   topElement = src.topElement; src.topElement = -1;
}

ArrayStack& ArrayStack::operator=(ArrayStack rhs)
{
    std::swap(maxCapacity, rhs.maxCapacity);
    std::swap(tab, rhs.tab);
    std::swap(length, rhs.length);
    std::swap(topElement, rhs.topElement);
    return *this;
}

ArrayStack::~ArrayStack()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        delete tab[i];
    }
    delete[] tab;
}

void ArrayStack::push(int element)
{
    if (maxCapacity <= length) {
        int newCapacity = maxCapacity + DEFAULT_CAPACITY;

        int** temp = new int* [newCapacity];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            temp[i] = tab[i];
        }
        for (int i = length; i < newCapacity; ++i) {
            temp[i] = nullptr;
        }

        delete[] tab;
        tab = temp;
        maxCapacity = newCapacity;
    }
   
    tab[length] = new int (element);
    ++length;

    topElement = element;
}

void ArrayStack::pop()
{
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw Empty_Stack();
    }

    --length;
    delete tab[length];
    tab[length] = nullptr;

    if (isEmpty()) {
        topElement = -1;
    }
    else {
        topElement = *tab[length-1];
    }
}

int ArrayStack::top() const
{
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw Empty_Stack();
    }
    return topElement;
}

bool ArrayStack::isEmpty() const
{
    return (length == 0);
}

int ArrayStack::size() const
{
    return length;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/af0SFV)

---

That being said, there is really no good reason to use an array of `int*` pointers at all. You should use an array of `int` values instead.  Then you will have a little less to manage manually:

ArrayStack.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "Stack.h"
#include "NotImplementedException.h"

class ArrayStack : public Stack
{
public:
    static const int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;

    // ATTENTION, pour chacune des méthodes, lorsque
    // vous créez sa définition dans le .cpp, vous devez
    // remplacer {} (et éventuellement son contenu) par un ;

    ArrayStack();
    ArrayStack(const ArrayStack &src);
    ArrayStack(ArrayStack &&src);
    ~ArrayStack();

    ArrayStack& operator=(ArrayStack rhs);

    void push(int element) override;
    void pop() override;
    int top() const override; 
    bool isEmpty() const override;
    int size() const override;

private:
    int length;
    int* tab;
    int topElement;
    int maxCapacity;
};
```

ArrayStack.cpp

```cpp
#include "ArrayStack.h"
#include <utility>

ArrayStack::ArrayStack() 
{
   maxCapacity = DEFAULT_CAPACITY;
   tab = new int [DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
   length = 0;
   topElement = -1;
}

ArrayStack::ArrayStack(const ArrayStack &src)
{
   maxCapacity = src.maxCapacity;
   tab = new int [maxCapacity];
   for (int i = 0; i < src.length; ++i) {
      tab[i] = src.tab[i];
   }
   length = src.length;
   topElement = src.topElement;
}

ArrayStack::ArrayStack(ArrayStack &&src)
{
   maxCapacity = src.maxCapacity; src.maxCapacity = 0;
   tab = src.tab; src.tab = nullptr;
   length = src.length; src.length = 0;
   topElement = src.topElement; src.topElement = -1;
}

ArrayStack& ArrayStack::operator=(ArrayStack rhs)
{
    std::swap(maxCapacity, rhs.maxCapacity);
    std::swap(tab, rhs.tab);
    std::swap(length, rhs.length);
    std::swap(topElement, rhs.topElement);
    return *this;
}

ArrayStack::~ArrayStack()
{
    delete[] tab;
}

void ArrayStack::push(int element)
{
    if (maxCapacity <= length) {
        int newCapacity = maxCapacity + DEFAULT_CAPACITY;

        int* temp = new int [newCapacity];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            temp[i] = tab[i];
        }

        delete[] tab;
        tab = temp;
        maxCapacity = newCapacity;
    }
   
    tab[length] = element;
    ++length;

    topElement = element;
}

void ArrayStack::pop()
{
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw Empty_Stack();
    }

    --length;

    if (isEmpty()) {
        topElement = -1;
    }
    else {
        topElement = tab[length-1];
    }
}

int ArrayStack::top() const
{
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw Empty_Stack();
    }
    return topElement;
}

bool ArrayStack::isEmpty() const
{
    return (length == 0);
}

int ArrayStack::size() const
{
    return length;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/SeAZ1u)

In which case, a better option would be to then replace the manual array with `std::vector` instead and let it do all of the heavy work for you:

ArrayStack.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "Stack.h"
#include "NotImplementedException.h"
#include <vector>

class ArrayStack : public Stack
{
public:
    static const int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;

    // ATTENTION, pour chacune des méthodes, lorsque
    // vous créez sa définition dans le .cpp, vous devez
    // remplacer {} (et éventuellement son contenu) par un ;

    ArrayStack();

    void push(int element) override;
    void pop() override;
    int top() const override; 
    bool isEmpty() const override;
    int size() const override;

private:
    std::vector<int> tab;
    int topElement;
};
```

ArrayStack.cpp

```cpp
#include "ArrayStack.h"

ArrayStack::ArrayStack() 
{
   tab.reserve(DEFAULT_CAPACITY);
   topElement = -1;
}

void ArrayStack::push(int element)
{
    tab.push_back(element);
    topElement = element;
}

void ArrayStack::pop()
{
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw Empty_Stack();
    }

    tab.pop_back();

    if (tab.empty()) {
        topElement = -1;
    }
    else {
        topElement = tab.back();
    }
}

int ArrayStack::top() const
{
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw Empty_Stack();
    }
    return topElement;
}

bool ArrayStack::isEmpty() const
{
    return tab.empty();
}

int ArrayStack::size() const
{
    return tab.size();
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/5uZHaM)

And then, finally, use `std::stack` instead:

ArrayStack.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "Stack.h"
#include "NotImplementedException.h"
#include <stack>

class ArrayStack : public Stack
{
public:
    // ATTENTION, pour chacune des méthodes, lorsque
    // vous créez sa définition dans le .cpp, vous devez
    // remplacer {} (et éventuellement son contenu) par un ;

    void push(int element) override;
    void pop() override;
    int top() const override; 
    bool isEmpty() const override;
    int size() const override;

private:
    std::stack<int> tab;
};
```

ArrayStack.cpp

```cpp
#include "ArrayStack.h"

void ArrayStack::push(int element)
{
    tab.push(element);
}

void ArrayStack::pop()
{
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw Empty_Stack();
    }

    tab.pop();
}

int ArrayStack::top() const
{
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw Empty_Stack();
    }
    return tab.top();
}

bool ArrayStack::isEmpty() const
{
    return tab.empty();
}

int ArrayStack::size() const
{
    return tab.size();
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/7vlbhB)

See how much cleaner that is? :-)

Comment: So it should look like what? I didn't lean 3/5/0 but could you give me the solution?

Comment: Sorry but can you shown me how it should look?

Comment: Can you show me how it should look like because i don't understand

Comment: My teacher what me to use the int** but no operator and no other constructor than the first one

Comment: @NicolasPellerin refresh the page to see the latest code. As for your teacher, insisting that you use an array of `int*` pointers`, and ignoring the Rule of 3/5/0, is not teaching you good C++ habits.

Comment: He may show it week later

Comment: OK, well, when he does, then you will already be a step ahead ;-)

Comment: But please I try copy the first delete, pop, and push but there is an debug error, and the test with max capacity and top eleemnt change fail.
ArrayStack::~ArrayStack()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        delete tab[i];
    }
    delete[] tab;
}

Comment: void ArrayStack::push(int element)
{

    if (maxCapacity <= length) {
        maxCapacity = +DEFAULT_CAPACITY;

        int** temp = new int* [maxCapacity];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            temp[i] = tab[i];
        }
        for (int i = length; i < maxCapacity; ++i) {
            temp[i] = nullptr;
        }

        delete[] tab;
        tab = temp;
    }
    ++length;
    tab[length] = new int(element);


    topElement = element;
}

Comment: void ArrayStack::pop()
{
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        throw Empty_Stack();
    }
    delete tab[this->length];

    --length;
    delete tab[length];
    tab[length] = nullptr;

    if (isEmpty()) {
        topElement = -1;
    }
    else {
        topElement = *tab[length - 1];
    }
}

Comment: That `push()` and `pop()` code is not the same as what I gave you. Look at my code again more carefully, compare it to your code line by line, and then fix your mistakes. Your `push()` is not incrementing `maxCapacity` at all, and it is incrementing `length` too soon. Your `pop()` is still suffering from the original bounds problems I described above the code.

Comment: I say I will see it after